# How to make child theme ignore a parent themes template

Tags: child-theme

I have a childtheme of twentythirteen in which i want to use the same template for pages and the blogposts-overview. But in twentythirteen is a page.php and an index.php. So I need override both, meaning I have to do all edits twice.

Any elegant solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `index.php` and format it the way you want.

Then create `page.php` and load the index file with something very simple like:

```
get_template_part('index'):
```

Note: This is untested and I am not able to test this right now. If there is a problem, leave a comment and I will run proper testing later and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [template filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) to force a template for specific kinds of requests.

In this example, we load the `page.php` template for the blog posts page:

```
function home_page_template(){
    return locate_template( 'page.php', false );
}
add_filter( 'home_template', 'home_page_template' );
```

Comment: Great solution however it doesn't work for templates which include functions as they're redeclared: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare executive_add_portfolio_body_class() (previously declared in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Websites\www.example.dev\wp-content\themes\modern-portfolio-pro\archive-portfolio.php:27) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Websites\www.example.dev\wp-content\themes\modern-portfolio-pro\archive-portfolio.php on line 30

Comment: that theme is doing something strange and non-standard if you're getting that error. it works without issue in all core-bundled themes. I'm not even sure why you'd declare functions in template files, poor theme structure.

Comment: Child themes template file. I copied over the template and renamed it but i like your solution and would like to find out why it doesn't work. Guess it does without the functions in the template file.

Comment: it should be loading a specific template in place of another, it doesn't make sense that more than one template would be loaded on the same request.